# Storing data parsed with Beatifulsoup4

Tags: excel, parsing, beautifulsoup, organization

I am trying to extract some information of intrest to an excelsheet with the headers NAMES, FORMULA, EXACTMASS, MOLWEIGHT, CAS but when i run my loop it adds each letter/number or byte(not sure if its right term) to a cell. I want it to store the whole information that it displays in the print and store it as a string in each box for each compound. When the loop starts again for the next link i want it to start in a new row. I am not sure where i am going wrong.

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import csv

def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    return soupdata


compoundlist = []
soup = make_soup("http://www.genome.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?ko00020")
i = 1
file = open("Compoundlist.csv", "w")
for record in soup.findAll("nobr"):
    compound = ''
    if (record.text[0] == "C" and record.text[1] == '0') or (record.text[0] == "C" and record.text[1] == '1'):
        compoundlist ="http://www.genome.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?cpd:" + record.text[:6] + '\n'
        file.write(compoundlist)
        # print(compoundlist)

file.close()
compoundinfo = []
linklist =open('Compoundlist.csv')

#
# def CASnumber(soup):
#     for tag in soup.findAll("div", {"style":"margin-left:3em"}):
#         tag = tag.text
#     return tag


for items in linklist:
    soupcomp = make_soup(items)
    for data in soupcomp.findAll("div", {"style":"width:555px;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:hidden"}):
            for NAMES in soupcomp.findAll("div", {"style":"width:555px;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:hidden"})[0]:
                NAMES = NAMES.text
    print(NAMES)
    for data in soupcomp.findAll("div", {"style":"width:555px;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:hidden"}):
            for INFO in soupcomp.findAll("div", {"style":"width:555px;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:hidden"})[0:3]:
                FORMULA = INFO.text
    print(FORMULA)
    for data in soupcomp.findAll("div", {"style":"width:555px;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:hidden"}):
            for INFO in soupcomp.findAll("div", {"style":"width:555px;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:hidden"})[0:4]:
                EXACTMASS = INFO.text
    print(EXACTMASS)
    for data in soupcomp.findAll("div", {"style":"width:555px;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:hidden"}):
            for INFO in soupcomp.findAll("div", {"style":"width:555px;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:hidden"})[0:5]:
                MOLWEIGHT = INFO.text
    print(MOLWEIGHT)
    for data in soupcomp.findAll("div", {"style":"width:555px;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:hidden"}):
            for CAS in soupcomp.findAll("div", {"style":"margin-left:3em"}):
                CAS = CAS.text
    print(CAS)
    with open("Compoundinfo.csv", 'a') as csv_file:
            writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
            writer.writerows([NAMES,FORMULA,EXACTMASS,MOLWEIGHT,CAS])
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1) Put `with open("Compoundinfo.csv", 'a') as csv_file:` before your `for items in linklist:` - There is no need to reopen the file at each loop;

2) The correct method for your case is `writer.writerow` (You have `writerows`).

`writerow` takes one dimensional data and `writerows` takes two dimensional data as parameters.